# Python architecture is 64bit

Tags: 64-bit, python-2.7, pip

It seems pyside module supports only 32bit Ubuntu,
so how can I install it...?

[image: screenshot]

```
Command "/usr/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-5m54Va/pyside/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-dUYgiI-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-5m54Va/pyside/
```

Comment: I see nowhere mentioning that pyside only supports 32bit Ubuntu. Any referece? I think this is your interpretation of the error. Do you have QT on your system?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting.

Answer (score 3):

To install PySide (Python bindings for Qt4) in all supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pyside  # for Python 2.x
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install python3-pyside  # for Python 3.x
```